# Java Gui issue. JFrame

Tags: java

Could someone help me figure out why both of my textboxes are not visible unless I click them, as well as my action-button unless I hover over it. I have the opacity checked and I’m sure it’s an easy fix but I’m having trouble figuring it out.

import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class SalaryMang {

```
private JFrame frame;
private JTextField SalaryField;

private Employee SalaryEmp;
private JLabel lblSsn;
private JTextField SSNField;

public SalaryMang(Employee newSalaryEmp) 
{
    SalaryEmp = newSalaryEmp;
    initialize();

}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 304, 225);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JLabel lblEnterSalary = new JLabel("Enter Salary:");
    lblEnterSalary.setBounds(35, 40, 80, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblEnterSalary);

    SalaryField = new JTextField();
    SalaryField.setVisible(true);
    SalaryField.setBounds(158, 37, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(SalaryField);
    SalaryField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            SalaryEmp.Write(SalaryField.getText());
            SalaryEmp.semi();
            SalaryEmp.Write(SSNField.getText());
            SalaryEmp.newLine();
        }
    });
    btnSubmit.setBounds(111, 106, 80, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnSubmit);

    lblSsn = new JLabel("SSN:");
    lblSsn.setBounds(35, 72, 46, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblSsn);

    SSNField = new JTextField();
    SSNField.setBounds(158, 68, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(SSNField);
    SSNField.setColumns(10);
}
```

}

Comment: call `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame **after** adding all components. Closing as duplicate. You're calling that **before** you've added all components to the JFrame.

Comment: frame.setVisible(true); // in my initialized field

Comment: Also don't use `setBounds(...)` and null layouts. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: `"frame.setVisible(true); // in my initialized field"` -- please re-read my comment. You're ignoring what I told you about **where** to call this. This is key.

Comment: nice! worked like a charm. I appreciate your patience with me :)